# Different US states: strictness of immigration questioning

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration

Does the standard and the strictness of the questioning at immigration vary in the different US states?

Comment: Well, I would guess immigration in Kansas is pretty laid back...  (no land borders and no international airports)

Comment: CBP is a federal agency, AFAIK this means they follow the same rules everywhere in the states... someone corrects me if I am wrong.

Comment: There is no way to answer the question.  Even within the same state the border crossing concerns differ.

Comment: @NeAnDerthal my former boss, a stateless Iranian born in Tehran, said that she always had a tough time of it in Miami, never at JFK.  I learned of this once after I asked how her vacation had been.  She said, "not bad, they only kept me for four hours this time."  She was in transit from Europe to the Caribbean.

Comment: @phoog I have harder times at IAD, not much at JFK. But still, they both follow the same regulations and policies.

Comment: @NeAnDerthal sure, but there is a considerable range of possible behavior that falls within those regulations and policies.

Comment: @phoong, if this was true and it is different from one state to another, then this would be a problem in the system that people can use in a bad way..

Comment: @NeAnDerthal that is possibly true.  I guess the question is whether JFK is more likely to mistakenly admit malevolent stateless Iranians or Miami is more likely to waste resources detaining harmless stateless Iranians.  I suspect the latter.  But it seems very likely to me that certain ports of entry will be easier to get through.  That is just human nature.

Answer (score 6):

CBP is a federal agency as Ne An Derthal mentioned.  As such they follow the same federally mandated guidelines at ALL postings, even the pre-clearance postings.

The only real differences are 1: the mood and mindset of the particular CBP agent you deal with, 2: the destination you are flying from.

The first is pretty hit and miss, as like ourselves CBP staff have good days and grumpy days, happy days and bored days.  Just the luck of the draw.

The second reason will always come into play, as some countries are known hot beds for issues, be it ag department problems, attempts to sneak around immigration rules, etc.

Comment: +1 Otherwise you would see people with bad intentions booking their flights to that airport with looser rules..

Comment: @NeAnDerthal you seem to assume that people with bad intentions aren't already doing that.  For all we know, they could be.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly what you asked, but I think you generally get an "easier" treatment using the preclearance facilities in Ireland at Dublin or especially Shannon. I don't think you'd slip anything past them (no more than anywhere else) but the process seems smoother and friendlier. Using BA Flight 1 which stops at Shannon for preclearance is my preferred way to enter the U.S. from Europe, in part because the immigration formalities are always completed quickly and with a smile.

The questioning is no different I should say, only the presentation.

Inside the territorial US I have not really seen much difference between the different ports. Sometimes the officers are having a nice day and you can have a pleasant chat while things are processed and sometimes they are in a bad mood and it's best to keep your answers short and to the point. Same as any other job I think.